# basedir in appsettings.json in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, appsettings, serilog

I started my new project in ASP.NET Core and I have a question.

I have 2 loggers:
a) nLog, that have it's config in nlog.config file
b) serilog, that have it's config in appsettings.json

At this moment, I have 2 locations to store logs:
fileName="${basedir}/logs/EPR/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log   - nLog
"SerilogFile": "logs/serilog-{Date}.txt"                  - serilog

My question is, how to get **basedir** catalog in **appsettings.json** file.

Comment: Did you solve that date append issue. If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to set an environment variable with the base path at startup:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("BASEDIR", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

Then use `"%BASEDIR%/logs/serilog-{Date}.txt"` in the config.

Answer (score 1):

**Short**: You can't in appsettings.json.

**Longer**: You can in code via the static `PlatformServices` class.

```
PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
```

and then use replace or whatever you seem fit to replace the `${basedir}` with the value returned by `ApplicationBasePath`, then pass it to your loggers configuration.

Sidenote: You shouldn't use `PlatformServices` outside of the `Startup`/`Programm` class, since they are static and bad to test etc.

Comment: Ehhh, it's bad that this is impossible:(

Comment: Is it still not supported